# Aspire 3 maximal external monitor resolution

Tags: hdmi, resolution, acer-aspire

I am not sure if the Aspire 3 Laptop (Aspire A317-51G) supports an external display with 4k resolution over HDMI.

The manufacturer information does not specify the maximum external resolution or the HDMI type: https://www.acer.com/us-en/support?search=NXHM0EZ00100903C403400;NX.HM0EZ.001;A317-51G&filter=global_download

The computer has a  i7-10510U and a  GeForce® MX230.

What is the maximum supported resolution/hz?

Answer (score 1):

According to the TechPowerUp article
[NVIDIA GeForce MX230](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-mx230.c3350),
this GPU accepts the resolutions of
1600x900, 1920x1080 and 2560x1440.
Only the first one is recommended for gaming.

All in all, I wouldn't recommend the GeForce MX230 for use with a
4K monitor.

Comment: I will check that with a screen